# Haskell beginner query

Tags: haskell

Hi I have a query about a simple haskell definition. I have a definition but I don't fully understand it.

The function takes in a list of functions and an item and returns a list formed by applying that function.

`applyAll = \fs -> \x -> map(\n -> n x) fs`

Could somebody explain what n does and why is fs outside the map function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spacing is misleading you. It looks like `map(\n -> n x)` is a function call, but the parentheses here are for grouping, not function call. `map` takes two arguments; the full call is `map (\n -> n x) fs`, where `(\n -> n x)` is the first argument (a lambda expression) and `fs` is the second.

The lambda `\n -> n x` is a function that takes a function as an argument and returns the result of applying that function to `x`. `n` is the argument here. The type of `\n -> n x` is `(a -> b) -> b` (where `a` is the type of `x`). If you have learned about sections yet, the lambda is equivalent to the section `($ x)`. If you haven't, ignore that last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The function definition:

```
applyAll = \fs -> \x -> map(\n -> n x) fs
```

is the same as:

```
applyAll fs x = map(\n -> n x) fs
```

Now you might ask, "What are those `->`s doing there if they are just arguments to my function `applyAll`. Haskell has no concept of multi-param functions. What you see as multiple arguments to a function is just many functions chained together *each* with a *single* argument. In the case of `applyAll`, it's just two functions chained together:

```
(applyAll fs) -> x = map (\n -> n x) fs
```

`applyAll fs` is one function chained to another argument identified as `x` to yield a list of values returned by `map`.

I could try this out in ghci:

```
Prelude> :t applyAll
applyAll :: [t -> b] -> t -> [b]
Prelude> :t applyAll xs

<interactive>:1:10: Not in scope: `xs'
Prelude> let xs = [1..5] 
-- hah, BOOM! I told you haskell's strongly typed... 
Prelude> :t applyAll xs

<interactive>:1:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> b0' with actual type `Integer'
    Expected type: [t0 -> b0]
      Actual type: [Integer]
    In the first argument of `applyAll', namely `xs'
    In the expression: applyAll xs
Prelude> let xs = [(1 +), (2 +), (3 *), (4 /)]
Prelude> :t xs
xs :: [Double -> Double]
Prelude> :t applyAll xs
applyAll xs :: Double -> [Double]
Prelude> :t applyAll
applyAll :: [t -> b] -> t -> [b]
Prelude> :t applyAll xs 3
applyAll xs 3 :: [Double]
Prelude> applyAll xs 3
[4.0,5.0,9.0,1.3333333333333333]
```

What's the type of `map`?

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This tells me that `map` takes a function - let's call it `f` and a list of values to return another list of values. The function `f` is one that takes a value of type `a` returning another of type `b`. So `map` goes on applying `f` to each value in the list `[a]` to return another list filled with values of type `b`.

In your `applyAll`, the function `f` is `\n -> n x`. This is a lambda expression(you might call it an anonymous function) taking a value identified by `n` and applying `x` to it. This goes on for every item in the input list identified by `[a]` in the type definition until it runs out to yield another list identified by `[b]` in the type definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function definition:

```
f x = 2*x + 1
```

This creates a new function `f`, which takes one argument. You could use it later like this:

```
main = print (f 3)
```

...which would print 7. Sometimes, it is convenient to define a function without giving it a name. The syntax for that is `\{- argument -} -> {- function body -}`; for example, we could do an anonymous version of `f` above this way:

```
main = print ((\x -> 2*x + 1) 3)
```

Now, your definition of `applyAll` is just doing this several times. We could explicitly name everything in `where` clauses if we wanted:

```
applyAll = outerMost where
    outerMost fs = mapApply where
         mapApply x = map applyToX fs where
             applyToX n = n x
```

...though I think you'll agree that the extra verbosity doesn't make things much more clear! A more natural (but less mechanical) translation away from anonymous functions would look like this:

```
applyAll fs x = map applyToX fs where
    applyToX n = n x
```

and now hopefully this can very nearly read like English: to apply all the functions `fs` to a single value `x`, we map "the function that applies a single function (which we temporarily name `n`) to the value `x`" over the list of all functions.